# get-childitem truncates name, fullname prior to format

Tags: powershell, buffer, get-childitem, truncated

I've been experimenting with a PowerShell combination of get-childitem, format-table, format-string, and out-file.

No matter what I try with ft -wrap -autoformat and various other options, the call of get-childitem truncates the name property to 35 characters total (30, excluding extension), e.g.:

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem 'c:\mypath\*' | ft -Wrap -AutoSize -Property name
```

Sample result (note: no ellipsis, but full extension):

```
myfilenametruncatesat30Charact.xlsx
```

Same behavior for fullname which truncates at 106 characters.

So it seems get-childitem is constrained by some type of buffer prior to piping it out to a format cmdlet...

I've seen references which speak of a 260 character limit for windows pathing, but these paths are in the 100 - 120 length range.

Any tips or clues as to why Powershell is truncating would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

You can use

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\mypath\*' | Select -ExpandProperty Name
```

**[Select-Object](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849895.aspx)**

> -ExpandProperty
>
> Specifies a property to select, and indicates that an attempt should
>   be made to expand that property. Wildcards are permitted in the
>   property name.
>
> For example, if the specified property is an array, each value of the
>   array is included in the output. If the property contains an object,
>   the properties of that object are displayed in the output.

**Edit**

```
PS C:\Users\Lieven\AppData\Local\Temp> gci myfilenametruncatesat30CharactAndThenSome.xlsx | ft -Wrap -AutoSize -Property
 name

Name
----
myfilenametruncatesat30CharactAndThenSome.xlsx
```

Comment: Thanks Lieven, but unfortunately I ended up with the same result.  Apparently 'Name' doesn't expand for Get-ChildItem...

Comment: @jjt - Strange, I've edited my answer to show what I get on my machine. Can you post a screenshot of the command and output? Can you post the result of a simple dir command in a command shell?

Comment: strange indeed!  I'm pulling my hair out.  I ran a DOS dir command and same thing - the file names/paths are getting truncated: c:\Research & Development\_Account Overview Data Project 0614\Accounts\myfilenametruncatesat30Charact.XLSX

Comment: I really would love to see a screenshot of the folder in both explorer and the command window.

Comment: Lieven, my apologies - after some further research I've discovered that the actual file names are legitimate.  The names are being truncated during file creation!  Argh!

Comment: lol - happens to all of us. You should be able to delete the question.